# Unity hub not working (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I can't create or open any project from lack of privileges (ERROR.LAUNCH_EDITOR.EACCES).

As soon as I press the create project button I receive a pop up with the name "Unity Launch error" and no error message (in the logs I get the ERROR.LAUNCH_EDITOR.EACCES error I mentioned in the post), the project gets "created" but no actual files or folders are created and if I exit the hub the project disappears, trying to open it gives me an non existent path error.

I installed the most recent version (that isn't a beta) using these instructions: https://docs.unity3d.com/hub/manual/InstallHub.html#install-hub-linux

This happens in any version even if I use the .AppImage version.

I checked the license and its fine, I reinstalled the editor just to be sure and all the folders have the correct file permissions.

This has been going on for months, how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you have `sudo` privilege when you setup the Unity Hub? Could be you've locked it up some way that doesn't allow the Hub to create files and folders. What do you get when you try `ls -l` on the executable?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ubuntu 20.04+ and an older unity version, then, you **SHOULD** install libconf 2-4 manually otherwise it wont let you create projects, just open console and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked online here and it works only with lower versions: https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download

I did not work for me in 20.04 either. I had to down grade because of it

Comment: which version worked for you?

Comment: I use the latest 18.04

Comment: But Unity has support for unity 20.4